# XPATH Exclude a class or start scraping after it

Tags: xpath

```
<p class="region-list"><a class="parent xh-highlight" href="/mediterranean-yacht-charters-1548.htm" title="Mediterranean Yachts for Charter - Summer">Mediterranean</a><a href="/croatia-yacht-charters-410.htm" title="Croatia Yachts for Charter - Summer" class="xh-highlight">Croatia</a>, <a href="/italy-yacht-charters-1525.htm" title="Italy Yachts for Charter - Summer" class="xh-highlight">Italy</a>, <a href="/montenegro-yacht-charters-1233.htm" title="Montenegro Yachts for Charter - Summer" class="xh-highlight">Montenegro</a></p>
```

I have this query:

```
//div[@class='hide-for-small']/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/p[@class='region-list']/a
```

Which returns:

```
Mediterranean
Croatia
Italy
Montenegro
```

However, I want to exclude the parent which is "Mediterranean" so I want to either say:

1. Skip the first `<a>` and grab the rest OR 2) Exclude the a `<a class="parent">`

I have been wrestling with this `@class!="parent"]` but can't seem to get this to work.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you can do both:

Skip the first `<a>` node:

```
//p[@class='region-list']/a[position()>1]/text()
```

or skip the `<a>` node with the specific class attribute value:

```
//p[@class='region-list']/a[not(@class='parent xh-highlight')]/text()
```